# OpenCart 2.3 - Adapting a theme - Language selection

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart2.3

I am developing a new theme from default one.

I notice that:

```
<?php echo $language; ?>
```

Generates:

```
<div class="pull-left">
<form action="http://192.168.0.1/opencart/index.php?route=common/currency/currency" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form-currency">
  <div class="btn-group open">
    <button class="btn btn-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
    <strong>$</strong>
    <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md">Currency</span> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button><div class="dropdown-backdrop"></div>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><button class="currency-select btn btn-link btn-block" type="button" name="EUR">€ Euro</button></li>
        <li><button class="currency-select btn btn-link btn-block" type="button" name="GBP">£ Pound Sterling</button></li>
        <li><button class="currency-select btn btn-link btn-block" type="button" name="USD">$ US Dollar</button></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" name="code" value="">
  <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://192.168.0.1/opencart/index.php?route=common/home">
</form>
</div>
```

But my template uses:

```
<li> <span class="dropdown-title">Currency :</span>
    <ul>
      <li><a class="active" href="#">USD</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">AUD</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">EUR</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

What shall be done to adapt `echo $language` to the new template needs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change its html markup by editing this file:

```
catalog\view\theme\default\template\common\language.tpl
```

Or if you have that file in your theme:

```
catalog\view\theme\{YOUR_THEME}\template\common\language.tpl
```